# Prompt does not appear

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to run a relatively simple switch case calculator, could you please rectify my mistake.
The prompt which i have put doesn't appear.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language = "javascript">
var x;
var a = 12;
var b = 20;
x= parseInt(prompt("Enter your Choice"));
switch(x)
{
Case 1 : document.write("The Sum is : ",a+b);
break;
Case 2 : document.write("The Difference is : ",a-b);
break;
Case 3 : document.write("The Product is : ",a*b);
break;
Case 4 : document.write("The quotient is : ",a/b);
break;
default : document.write("Invalid Choice");
break;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so `case` and `Case` are not the same. `case` without the capital "C" is the correct spelling.

Comment: did i type "case" somewhere?

Comment: @KartikeyGaur switch-case

Comment: you should change Case to case,that's gonna work

Comment: Thank You so much Federico, i was so frustrated , thanks a lot :D

Comment: Thank You guys so much for your help , Thanks a lot Federico and xianshenglu and Ivan

Comment: <script language = "javascript"> is deprecated. Instead use <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: If anyone posts an answer i will upvote it , Thanks a lot i am so relieved

Comment: no probelm, just next time, as @gurvinder372 said, take a look at your browser's developer tools' console. Usually at that point it becomes pretty clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Case` to `case`, JavaScript is case sensitive programming language.

Have a look [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_02.htm) for more info..!!

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <script language = "javascript">
  
    var x;
    var a = 12;
    var b = 20;
    x= parseInt(prompt("Enter your Choice"));
    switch(x)
    {
    case 1 : document.write("The Sum is : ",a+b);
    break;
    case 2 : document.write("The Difference is : ",a-b);
    break;
    case 3 : document.write("The Product is : ",a*b);
    break;
    case 4 : document.write("The quotient is : ",a/b);
    break;
    default : document.write("Invalid Choice");
    break;
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is your same code in working condition.

Answer (score 1):

you capitilized the C in Case, as javascript is case sensetive it won't run.

```
var x;
var a = 12;
var b = 20;
x= parseInt(prompt("Enter your Choice"));
switch(x)
{
case 1 : document.write("The Sum is : ",a+b);
break;
case 2 : document.write("The Difference is : ",a-b);
break;
case 3 : document.write("The Product is : ",a*b);
break;
case 4 : document.write("The quotient is : ",a/b);
break;
default : document.write("Invalid Choice");
break;
}
```

this should work.